# IOS Number Of Sections In Table View Dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am creating an app where users can store an object in Core Data.  I have the Objects being pulled into a UITableView and everything is working correctly there.  I now want to separate the objects into a possible of 1-3 different sections based on choices in a UISegmentedControl.

Currently I have this to create the 1 section and populate the cells of that section with my objects

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.fetchedDiscs.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DiscCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Configure Cell
    Disc *currentDisc = [self.fetchedDiscs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = currentDisc.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentDisc.brand;

    return cell;
}
```

So the main question is how to dynamically change the number of sections and number of rows in section?

The Segmented control returns values such as   Option 1, Option 2, Option 3.  The only way I can think of is to loop through my fetchedDiscs array and separate that into an array for each section.  Then I can return the number of arrays if they exists and I can get the count of each array to get the number of rows in each section.   But then I get to the problem of How to get the CellForRowAtIndextPath to work correctly with three arrays.

Basically there has to be a better more logical way to do this.  I am just not sure how.

Comment: What you have described is pretty much how you would do it.  The `indexPath` passed to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` contains a `section` property, so you know which array to use for a given cell

Comment: you may need to first to find a nice tutorial regarding you seem to be a lack of some basic knowledge about working with `UITableView` instances. any possible answer would be too complex for your simple question, and you will probably donwvote it if you don't understand or cannot use it to implement the final solution in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let, you have a dictionary named dataSource that contains 'x' number of array as value for key "key1", "key2", .. "keyX". You can do this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[dataSource allKeys] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Get the array object form key. I am considering 'keySection' as an example
    return [[dataSource objectForKey:@"keySection"] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DiscCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[dataSource objectForKey:keySection] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

    return cell;
}
```

Note: I wrote the code in this editor, excuse any mistakes, I just tried to share the idea. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: So this seems to help a lot and does make some sense but as I am super knew to Obj-c I do not know how to set up the dictionary properly.  if in my fetchedDisc array I have details of my disc objects and on the type property I have either option1, option2, or option3 how do I split the array in a dictionary of arrays split by those keys?

Comment: @CodyJamesTooker> Post your data.